# In Rust, is being able to use a structs methods from an unimported module expected behavior?

Tags: rust, methods, struct, module

I'm still quite new to programming in Rust, but I do have experience with C/C++ programming.

The crux of my question has to do with this code:

`src/main.rs`:

```rust
use storefront::store_model;

fn main() {
    let mut store_model: store_model::StoreModel = store_model::new_store_model();
    store_model.add_product(
        String::from("Test Product"),
        123.45,
        String::from("This is a Test Product."),
        String::from("This is a Test Product for a test."),
        42,
    );

    store_model.add_product(
        String::from("Wonderfon"),
        77.34,
        String::from("This is the 1998 Wonderfon, brought back in 2022!"),
        String::from("Call like it's the 1990's! The Wonderfon is back in all its glory!"),
        77,
    );

    store_model.add_product(
        String::from("Test Product 2.0"),
        123.45,
        String::from("This is the Test Product 2.0!"),
        String::from("This is a Test Product 2.0 for another test."),
        42,
    );

    match store_model.product(0) {
        None => println!("That isn't an item!"),
        Some(p) => {
            let (product, quantity) = p;
            println!("{}", product.name());
        }
    }

    match store_model.product(1) {
        None => println!("That isn't an item!"),
        Some(p) => println!("{:?}", p),
    }

    match store_model.product(2) {
        None => println!("That isn't an item!"),
        Some(p) => println!("{:?}", p),
    }

    match store_model.product(3) {
        None => println!("That isn't an item!"),
        Some(p) => println!("{:?}", p),
    }
}
```

I didn't expect to be able to use the `name()` method for product (which is a struct I defined in a separate module, `src/product.rs`). What I did expect was some sort of error.

Is this expected behavior in Rust? If it is, is it explained somewhere, or is there any resources pointing to this behavior? I own a copy of *The Rust Programming Language* (for Rust 2018) and am currently on chapter 9. If it's further than what I've read to, where is it?

Comment: If you would add the full code to https://replit.com and share it, it would be easier to help you because I don't know, for me there is not enough information about product.rs it is easier to figure it out in code than to describe it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. I don't know if it's mentioned specifically in *The Rust Programming Language*, but here is [the Rust Reference on method call expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html):

> Then, for each candidate type `T`, search for a visible method with a receiver of that type in the following places:
>
> - `T`'s inherent methods (methods implemented directly on `T`).
> - Any of the methods provided by a visible trait implemented by `T`. …

So, an inherent method is **always** a candidate for method lookup. Inherent methods are those which are declared in `impl Product {` blocks, as opposed to declared by traits. If the method had been instead part of a trait, you would indeed have to import that trait.

---

Here's some useful context about how Rust's compiler works — these do not *specify* the behavior you oberved, but they are how it is *possible.* In Rust, unlike C++,

- There are no header files; instead, the compiler produces an `.rmeta` file describing the contents of a library when it compiles that library, and then when it compiles a dependent of that library it reads that file.
- The compilation unit — the amount of code that the compiler analyzes all at once — is the *crate*, not the *file.*

So, when you compile *your crate,* `src/main.rs` and `src/product.rs` are part of that crate and part of the same compilation unit. The compiler is free to use information from any of these files when working on the code in one of them. There is no possibility of a method existing but not being declared, like there is in C++.

In Rust, whether an item (type, function, method, module …) is visible in a given circumstance is a language design choice made to support good software engineering; it is never a case of *the compiler not knowing about the item.*

Answer (score 0):

If we have

```rust
// src/product.rs
struct Product;
impl Product {
    fn name(&self) {}
}
```

And somewhere else:

```rust
let p = crate::product::Product;
p.name();
// ^ this is syntactic sugar to the following:
crate::product::Product::name(&p);
```

So yes, it is expected behaviour.